# Can't install rvm-capistrano gem

Tags: rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I just upgraded to the lastest RVM (1.12.3) and am trying to install the rvm-capistrano gem.

I already have the latest `capistrano, capistrano-ext, and capistrano-colors gems` installed.

This is the line I added to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
```

When I do a `'bundle install'` I get the following error:

===========================================

> /home/larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@stuptues/bin/rake
>       Error:Error:[rake --tasks] rake aborted!
>
> uninitialized constant Capistrano
>
> /home/larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@stuptues/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.0.2/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb:3:in `'
>
> /home/larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@stuptues/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in
>   `require'
>
> /home/larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@stuptues/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in
>   `rescue in block in require'
>
> /home/larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@stuptues/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in
>   `block in require'
>
> /home/larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@stuptues/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
>   `each'
>
> /home/larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@stuptues/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>
> /home/larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@stuptues/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in
>   `require'
>
> /home/larry/RubyMine/StupidTuesday/config/application.rb:7:in `'
>
> /home/larry/RubyMine/StupidTuesday/Rakefile:4:in `require'
>
> /home/larry/RubyMine/StupidTuesday/Rakefile:4:in `'
>
> ================================================

Here is the "offending" line from the newly-added
`rvm-capistrano/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb` file:

> Capistrano::Configuration.instance(true).load do

This seems like it should just work. Does anyone know why it isn't?

Thanks,

Larry

Comment: That error (and an identical one related to rails generators) occurred when the "gem rvm-capistrano" line was placed _before_ the "gem capistrano" line in my Gemfile.

When I placed the "rvm-capistrano" line _after_  the "capistrano" one it worked fine. I didn't realize there was an order dependency in the Gemfile.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

-- Larry

Answer (score 0):

just update the version of rvm-capistrano gem:

```
bundle update rvm-capistrano
```

this problem was already reported and fixed.